# SVG Chrome FireFox difference use defs elements, relations between figures

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I'm searching for a week a solution to solve a problem. When I'm open a page with Chrome and FireFox I've got a diffrences:
*DOM structure works well in FireFox, not in Chrome;
*Video-animation works well in Chrome, not in FireFox: by pressing not only on clock-wing, but also to button.

Thank you, and I apologize for the size of the file. I'll be happy in you help to solve even one of these problems

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function blinker_set_value(html_dom_id, value)
        {
            var blinker = document.getElementById(html_dom_id+".blinker");
            if(!blinker) return;

            if(value == "open") {
                alert("БЛИНКЕР ПЕРЕВЕДЕН ВО ВКЛЮЧЕННОЕ ПОЛОЖЕНИЕ.");
                blinker.setAttribute('xlink:href','#blinker.green');
                } else {
                alert("БЛИНКЕР ПЕРЕВЕДЕН В ОТКЛЮЧЕННОЕ ПОЛОЖЕНИЕ.");
                blinker.setAttribute('xlink:href','#blinker.red');
            }
        }

        //change visible position (vkl/otkl)
        function blinker_open(button, miliSec)
        {   
            setTimeout(function() {
                var blinker = get_parent(button);
                var name = blinker_get_name(blinker);
                var element_id = blinker.getAttribute('id');
                request('blinker.open', name, element_id);
            }, miliSec);
        }

        function blinker_close(button, miliSec)
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var blinker = get_parent(button);
                var name = blinker_get_name(blinker)
                var element_id = blinker.getAttribute('id');
                request('blinker.close', name, element_id);
            }, miliSec);
        }

        //get parentElement from click button
        function get_parent(button)
        {
            prnt = button;
            prntId = prnt.getAttribute('id');
            while (prnt != null) {
                if (prntId == "view_button_blinker.blinker" || prntId == "view_button_cover.cover") {
                    return prnt;
                }
                prnt = prnt.parentNode;
                prntId = prnt.getAttribute('id');
            }
            alert("SCRIPT ERROR: No coincidence. Check <use id = idName>  in DOM hierarchy");
        }

        //remove format from string
        function blinker_get_name(blinker)
        {
            var name = blinker.getAttribute('id');
            name = name.replace(".blinker", "");
            return name;
        }

        function request(request_name, value, element_id)
        {
            var element_name = value;
            if(request_name == "blinker.open") blinker_set_value(element_name, 'open');
            else if(request_name == "blinker.close") blinker_set_value(element_name, 'close');
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body style="margin:0; border:0">
    <svg version="1.1" id="id_hash_asddfdsfsd"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="450px"
    viewBox="0 0 800 600" style="enable-background:new 0 0 201 151;" xml:space="preserve">


        <defs>

            <g id="active_element_button">

                <g id="blinker.red">
                    <circle id="diffrFig1" style="fill:red;stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="-45.125" cy="-44.375" r="8.5"/>

                    <circle onclick="blinker_open(this, 700)" cursor="pointer" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="57.012" cy="-44.375" r="8.5">
                        <animate
                        attributeName="fill"  
                        begin="0s" dur="0.5s"  
                        values ="white; #E2F9E5; white;"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"
                        />  
                        <animate
                        attributeName="fill"  
                        begin="mouseover" end="mouseout" dur="1.5s" 
                        values ="#ACF0B6; #3EDB53;"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"   
                        /> 
                        <set  attributeName="fill" to="#16D430" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />

                    </circle>
                    <g onclick="blinker_open(this, 700)" cursor="pointer">
                        <g>

                            <path style="stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M7.647,10.771l-1.11-63.55
                            c-24.16,0.421-43.739,13.608-54.25,32.839L7.647,10.771z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>

                            <path style="stroke:#3F7DA6;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M7.83,5.486l-54.485,32.737
                            C-34.75,58.033-12.999,69.297,8.912,68.784L7.83,5.486z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>

                            <path style="stroke:#3F7DA6;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M3.191,8.285l55.593,30.814
                            c11.384-20.539,10.085-44.683-1.315-63.4L3.191,8.285z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>
                        </g>

                        <g>
                            <g transform="translate(0.2, 0.3)">
                                <polygon style="fill:#808080;stroke:#666666;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="-8.762,15.419 
                                -8.926,-0.842 5.238,-8.83 19.568,-0.557 19.732,15.704 5.568,23.691  "/>
                            </g>
                            <circle style="fill:#666666;stroke:#4D4D4D;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="5.75" cy="8" r="7"/>
                        </g>

                        <animateTransform begin="click"
                        attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                        from="0 5.75 8" to="-59 5.75 8" dur="0.7s" fill="freeze" />

                        <animateTransform begin="diffrFig1.click"
                        attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                        from="0 5.75 8" to="-59 5.75 8" dur="0.7s" fill="freeze" />
                    </g>
                </g>


                <g id="blinker.green">
                    <circle style="fill:green;stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="57.012" cy="-44.375" r="8.5"/>

                    <circle id="diffrFig2" onclick="blinker_close(this, 700)" cursor="pointer" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="-45.125" cy="-44.375" r="8.5">
                        <set  attributeName="fill" to="#FF3333" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                        <animate
                        attributeName="fill"  
                        begin="0s" dur="0.5s"  
                        values ="white; #FFECEC; white;"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"
                        />  
                        <animate
                        attributeName="fill"  
                        begin="mouseover" end="mouseout" dur="1.5s" 
                        values ="#FFDFDF; #FF6C6C;"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"   
                        /> 
                        <set  attributeName="fill" to="#FF0303" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" 
                        />
                    </circle>
                    <g onclick="blinker_close(this, 700)" cursor="pointer">
                        <g transform="translate(0, -0.5)">
                            <path style="stroke:#3F7DA6;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M4.706,10.474l55.045-31.781
                            C47.669-42.234,26.643-52.964,4.729-52.834L4.706,10.474z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>

                            <path style="stroke:#3F7DA6;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M9.419,8.071l-55.048-31.781
                            c-11.556,20.016-10.861,44.5,0.209,63.414L9.419,8.071z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>

                            <path style="stroke:#3F7DA6;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M4.722,5.371v63.563
                            c23.485-0.001,43.972-12.842,54.814-31.889L4.722,5.371z">
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="white" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
                                <set  attributeName="fill" to="#D9D9D9" begin="mousedown" end="mouseout" />
                            </path>
                        </g>

                        <g>
                            <g transform="translate(0, 0.5)">
                                <polygon style="fill:#808080;stroke:#666666;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="-8.762,15.419 
                                -8.926,-0.842 5.238,-8.83 19.568,-0.557 19.732,15.704 5.568,23.691  "/>
                            </g>
                            <circle style="fill:#666666;stroke:#4D4D4D;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="5.75" cy="8" r="7"/>

                        </g>

                        <animateTransform begin="click"
                        attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                        from="0 5.75 8" to="59 5.75 8" dur="0.7s" fill="freeze" />

                        <animateTransform begin="diffrFig2.click"
                        attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace"
                        from="0 5.75 8" to="59 5.75 8" dur="0.7s" fill="freeze" />
                    </g>
                </g>

            </defs>

            <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="300" fill="lightgray" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="lightgray"/>
            <rect x="5" y="5" width="790" height="38" fill="orange" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="lightgray" />
            <rect x="10" y="50" width="780" height="240" fill="lightgray" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="gray" />

            <g transform="translate(75, 75)">
                <g transform="translate(325, 100)">
                    <use id="view_button_blinker.blinker" xlink:href="#blinker.green" />
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute can't be used to set xlink:href attributes. You need setAttributeNS instead so

```
blinker.setAttribute('xlink:href','#blinker.green');
```

needs to become

```
blinker.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href','#blinker.green');
```

etc.

Also animation of things pointed to by `<use>` elements doesn't currently work in Firefox. You need to remove the `<use>` element and put the markup inline at that point.

Comment: There had been no change while setAttributeNS become to the setAttributeNS construction. And Chrome node-switch doesn't work still